# mysql -u root command is not working in hadoop

Tags: mysql, hadoop, sqoop

I have tried to go to mysql in hadoop.

but its showing command not found.

but it should allow me to mysql. i have to create one table and try to send the data to the hive using sqoop.

Please help me.

what might be the issue.

Thanks,
Anbu k

Comment: We need more details than this to help. Things like commands used, operating systems, error messages received etc

Comment: i am going to work on sqoop for that i am trying to create a table in mysql.
but when i tried to open mysql 
the below query is not working
[cloudera@localhost ~]$ mysql -u root
bash: mysql: command not found
[cloudera@localhost ~]$

how could check whether MYSQL is available or not. I am new of this, please help..

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are trying to access mysql from your local system and are trying to create new table. 
A few pre checks can resolve your problem. 
First check if mysql is installed. If it is installed, you need to start the service.

```
 sudo service mysqld start
```

Then try

```
mysql -u root -P
```

Comment: Hi Gupta,

How could i check whether my sql is installed or not.

as u said i checked with above query

[cloudera@localhost ~]$ sudo service mysqld start
mysqld: unrecognized service
[cloudera@localhost ~]$

Comment: In which machine are you trying to execute this? If its a VM then am suspecting that your mySQL is not installed for you. If it installed, you cod usually find it in /usr/lib/mysql folder in Linux. Check some tutorials on how to install and run mysql. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Below commands will help you to install Mysql in Cloudera distribution.

```
sudo yum install mysql-server
```

Before you start to use Mysql database you need to start Mysql daemons.

```
sudo service mysqld start
```